# How do I use TypeApplications with typeclass methods, and why does GHCi infer a type that I can't use?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, ghci, type-families

## Summary

I have a typeclass for which I want to write some 'generic terms'. I have two questions:

1. Using `:t` to ask GHCi for the type of a generic term works, but using that inferred type fails- why?
2. How do I use `TypeApplications` with the methods of a typeclass?

I am using **GHC 8.8.4**. For both problems I have the following example `Main.hs` containing a typeclass `F` and type `Empty` which is an instance of `F`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoStarIsType #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
module Main where

import GHC.Types (Type)

class F (f :: k -> Type) where
  type Plus f (a :: k) (b :: k) :: k

  zero :: f a
  plus :: f a -> f b -> f (Plus f a b)

data Empty (a :: Type) = Empty

instance F Empty where
  type Plus Empty a b = (a, b)
  zero     = Empty
  plus _ _ = Empty
```

## 1. Inferred Types don't work?

I would like to construct a generic term of the typeclass `F`. For example, `plus zero zero`.
When I ask GHCi for the type of this term it gives me what I would expect:

```
*Main> :t plus zero zero
plus zero zero :: F f => f (Plus f a b)
```

Surprisingly, if I try to *assign* this term, I get an error. Namely, if I add the following to `Main.hs`:

```
-- This doesn't work.
plusZero :: F f => f (Plus f a b)
plusZero = plus zero zero
```

Reloading the file in GHCi complains with the error:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Plus f a0 b0’ with ‘Plus f a b’
      Expected type: f (Plus f a b)
        Actual type: f (Plus f a0 b0)
      NB: ‘Plus’ is a non-injective type family
      The type variables ‘a0’, ‘b0’ are ambiguous
    • In the expression: plus zero zero
      In an equation for ‘plusZero’: plusZero = plus zero zero
```

My first question is: why does GHCi seem to infer the type, but reject it when I annotate the term explicitly?

## 2. Using `TypeApplications` instead of annotations

I can get around the first problem simply by annotating the types of `zero` terms:

```
-- This works
plusZero1 :: forall f a b . F f => f (Plus f a b)
plusZero1 = plus (zero :: f a) (zero :: f b)
```

However, this is a little clunky when terms get large. What I want to do is use `TypeApplications`. I tried this:

```
-- This doesn't work
plusZero2 :: forall f a b . F f => f (Plus f a b)
plusZero2 = plus @f @a @b zero zero
```

But GHCi complains:

```
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘f’
      Expected a type, but ‘f’ has kind ‘k -> *’
    • In the type ‘f’
      In the expression: plus @f @a @b zero zero
      In an equation for ‘plusZero2’: plusZero2 = plus @f @a @b zero zero
    • Relevant bindings include
        plusZero2 :: f (Plus f a b) (bound at Main.hs:36:1)
```

Strangely, if I first define additional functions `plus'` and `zero'` as follows, everything works as expected:

```
zero' :: forall f a . F f => f a
zero' = zero

plus' :: forall f a b . F f => f a -> f b -> f (Plus f a b)
plus' = plus

-- This works fine
plusZero3 :: forall f a b . F f => f (Plus f a b)
plusZero3 = plus' @f @a @b zero' zero'
```

So it seems I haven't understood how `TypeApplications` works with typeclass methods.
How can I use a type application with `plus` and `zero` without having to define the additional functions `plus'` and `zero'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Inferred Types don't work?

In your example GHC can indeed infer the type, but it can not accept your signature. It may seem counter-intuitive, but it does make sense if you think about the general picture.

`Plus f a b` is a non-injective type family. For all GHC knows while type checking, it could be defined as `Plus f a b = a` for all `f`, `a`, and `b`.

Pretend we already have defined a term (I add `forall`s for clarity)

```
foo :: forall f a b. F f => f (Plus f a b)
```

and we write

```
bar :: forall f a b. F f => f (Plus f a b)
bar = foo
```

This should not type check (!) because is it inherently ambiguous. The programmer, being a human, probably would expect the compiler to infer these types:

```
bar :: forall f a b. F f => f (Plus f a b)
bar = foo @f @a @b
```

However, there might be other correct inferred types! Indeed, if `Plus` is defined as mentioned above, this would also type check:

```
bar :: forall f a b. F f => f (Plus f a b)
bar = foo @f @a @String
```

Using that, `foo` will produce `f (Plus f a String)` which is the same as `f (Plus f a b)`, so everything type checks. Since the programmer might have intended to use something else than `@b`, we stop here reporting the ambiguity with a type error.

---

Technically, what happens during inference is this: the call to the poltmorphic `foo` is linked to fresh unknown type variables:

```
bar :: forall f a b. F f => f (Plus f a b)
bar = foo @xf @xa @xb
```

Then, unification happens: the type of `foo @xf @xa @xb` is `xf (Plus xf xa xb)` and this is unified with the provided signature to find the unknowns:

```
xf (Plus xf xa xb) ~ f (Plus f a b)
```

From that we apply the unification algorithm:

```
xf ~ f
Plus xf xa xb ~ Plus f a b
```

So we find the type for the unknown `xf`, and substituting we get:

```
xf ~ f
Plus f xa xb ~ Plus f a b
```

However, we stop here. We can not infer `xa ~ a` and `xb ~ b` since the type family is not injective.

---

> 2. Using TypeApplications instead of annotations

The issue is that there is a hidden kind `@k` argument, since that occurs in the class. Use `:t +v` to show the real type with all the `forall`s:

```
> :t +v plus
plus
  :: forall k (f :: k -> *) (a :: k) (b :: k).
     F f =>
     f a -> f b -> f (Plus f a b)
```

Passing `@k` too works:

```
plusZero2 :: forall k (f :: k -> Type) a b . F f => f (Plus f a b)
plusZero2 = plus @k @f @a @b zero zero
```

Alternatively, make the compiler infer that `@k`:

```
plusZero2 :: forall f a b . F f => f (Plus f a b)
plusZero2 = plus @_ @f @a @b zero zero
```

Comment: The clarification with type inference was extremely clear- thanks! I guess it raises the question - can type families in a typeclass be made injective so that the types can be inferred?

Comment: @statusfailed Unfortunately, no. There is a GHC extension exactly for injective type classes, but it's almost useless since even with that, injectivity is not exploited in type inference. Rumors say the GHC devs are not enabling that until someone actually proves type safety in the presence of such inference. You might want to look at _data families_ instead, which are injective, but define a new type in each instance.